# How to use different versions with git paths in a Python module's setup.cfg?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, dependency-management, python-packaging

In the setup.cfg of a module you can maintain dependencies like

```
install_requires =
    some_package_on_pipy >=2.28.1,<3.0
```

For our local modules we use git tags, something like

```
install_requires =
    some_local_package@git+ssh://git@gitlab.company.com/some_local_package@v0.1.0
```

but so far we could not find a way to use `>=` or `<` to be more flexible on the
dependencies. With git tags it is always hardcoded and it will become really annoying at some point.

We also had look at Poetry but could not find a solution there.

Is there some solution without setting up some local PyPI thingy, e.g. point the setup.cfg to a folder with a bunch of wheels for all possible versions?

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I think you need `--find-links` which can point to a flat directory containing whl files