# How to get a git repo requirement with flexible version

Tags: python, pip

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584552/how-to-state-in-requirements-txt-a-direct-github-source) question that explains how to state a direct GitHub source in a requirements.txt file, but it only provides the option of selecting fixed versions. Is it possible to specify a range like `>=2.0,<2.1` as for regular packages?

Comment: Not possible as far as I know. -- Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76488581